# Is there a way to wrap jQuery's isArrayLike?

Tags: javascript, jquery, monkeypatching

I'm trying to handle a conflict between XenForo and an essential plugin.  Neither is code I can directly modify.  jQuery 1.11.3 is the version in use, and that can't be upgraded either.

I can wrap the calling function with a try/catch and avoid the conflict, but the real fix would involve wrapping jQuery's isArrayLike with a try/catch.

isArrayLike is in the (current version) jQuery source at line 464 in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L464

What I need to catch seems to be exactly what was being debated in https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-isarraylike-for-consistency with regard to isArrayLike throwing errors when passed invalid types.

So, since jQuery's isArrayLike isn't exposed, is there any way to either wrap it, or worst case, get in there and replace it?

Edit: Note, all the comments so far are trying to debug the error itself.  That is not my question.  I am asking if there is any way to access isArrayLike, so it can be wrapped with another function.

Comment: State what exactly you need to catch in the question itself. That forum thread is too broad.

Comment: On hover for the mail and alert popups, XenForo.ExtLoader is passing *something* to $.each(), which in turn is calling isArraylike, which is then throwing a TypeError.  I can wrap XenForo.ExtLoader to suppress the error and show the popup, but that's catching the problem too high up - the popup ends up unpopulated.  If I can find a way to wrap isArraylike to catch that TypeError, I should be able to get each() to still populate the popup.

Comment: What is the `something` that causes the TypeError?

Comment: I'm not sure.  But as it's coming from something sent by Xen, and the error's being triggered by jQuery, I don't have the ability to directly fix the cause of the error either, hence the need to monkeypatch after the fact.

Comment: If you patch jQuery by changing in `isArrayLike` the first line `var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,` to `var length = !!obj && "length" in Object(obj) && obj.length,`, does that solve the issue? Note that I added the `Object` call.

Comment: I don't have the ability to change jQuery's code, hence looking for a way to access that function to wrap it.

Comment: Open your debugger, set "pause on exceptions", and see what kind of thing causes the error.

Comment: Tried that, but WAY too much noise from Xen; the error's buried deep enough, I can't even quite figure what's triggering it.  Again, something that'd be much much simpler to work on, if I can find a way to wrap isArraylike.

Comment: Reading some on proxy traps in ES6, I wondering if perhaps that might be a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest replacing the jQuery `each` and `map` methods, which seem to be the only methods calling on `isArrayLike`, except for `makeArray`. But the fix I am suggesting is not necessary for the latter method.

Add this:

```
(function ($, origEach, origMap) {
    $.each = function (elems, callback, arg) {
        return origEach.call(this, Object(elems), callback, arg);
    };
    $.map = function (elems, callback, arg) {
        return origMap.call(this, Object(elems), callback, arg);
    };
})(jQuery, jQuery.each, jQuery.map);
```

It alters the first argument that is passed to `map` or `each`: it gets wrapped in an `Object` call, which changes nothing when it is an array, but turns the argument in an object if it is not an object (for some odd reason).

#### Patching jQuery

If you can use a patched version of jQuery, just store a copy of jQuery, and modify this line in the function `isArrayLike`:

```
var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,
```

to:

```
var length = !!obj && "length" in Object(obj) && obj.length,
```

It should not be a problem for `XenForo`, as long as you explicitly add the patched jQuery via another `script` tag, *after* having included `XenForo`. The latest jQuery object overwrites the previous one, so `XenForo` will then also use the patched version, even though it included the non-patched jQuery library itself.

The downside of patching is that you cannot upgrade jQuery (implicitly with a `XenForo`upgrade) unless you patch it every time you upgrade (until the version where it is no longer necessary).

That is a problem you won't have with the first solution.

Comment: That gets closer, but it's still too high a level.  It looks as though isArraylike is being passed an empty string rather than an object.  The first line of isArraylike *should* be catching that, but it doesn't check the length until after it looks for obj.length, hence the "in" TypeError:
var length = "length"in obj && obj.length

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggested `Object(obj)` as a patch in that `in` expression. But apparently you cannot patch jQuery (why?). So then this is the closest you can get, IMO.

Comment: XenForo's dependant on that specific jQuery.  It does look like later jQuery versions added a fix which would catch this problem ( var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length ).  As isArraylike isn't externally accessible, the best monkeypatch possible may end up being a replacement $.each that incorporates a later (fixed) version of isArraylike.

Comment: I think you can just include a patched jQuery and the generated jQuery object will just overwrite the one that XenForo included. As long as you include it after XenForo, it should be OK. Personally I think it is a bad idea to include a patched implementation of `$.each` in your code, which would call a corrected version of `isArrayLike`, as you would need to write the other logic of `$.each` as well. I really think it is better to call the original `$.each` with a modified argument (with `Object`), like I suggested in my answer.